# AngularJS - ng-click in directive's link function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm working on a directive, and in the `link` function, while iterating over a array model, want to append elements to the page with `ng-click` handlers attached to them. Something like this:

```
app.directive('foo', function(){
   restrict: 'A',
   link: function(scope, elem){
      ... // some logic

      for (var i = 1; i < numberOfPages + 1; i++) {
         elem.append('<li ng-click="bar('+i+')">'+i+'</li>');
      }
   }
});
```

But the `ng-click` handlers are dead on arrival. How can I make the handlers behave as expected?

Comment: See the [compile docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)

Comment: While you can use `$compile` to resolve your problem, it is not a good idea. Try to use templates with bindings instead.

Comment: That's the thing, I don't need nor want bindings. The watchers are slowing things down.

Comment: @Metzger `link` function should work primarily like a controller, and it should not modify the view directly. Adding event listeners is ok, but create/remove parts is not.You used MVC pattern in a wrong way.

Comment: Ok, give me a solution that doesn't involve two way data binding. If there isn't any, there's not much I can do.

Answer (score 3):

In AngularJS, you can't really append directives to your custom directive without having to do some weird `$compile` logic to get the `ngClick` directives to register. Probably something like:

```
// include $compile
// ... append li elements
scope.$apply(function() {
  $compile(elem)(scope);
});
```

I have no idea if that works by the way, so don't hold me accountable if it doesn't. Generally, the way you solve this problem is with a directive that looks like this:

```
angular.directive('pager', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AEC',
    scope: {
      numPages: '=pager',
      pageFn: '='
    },
    template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="page in pages" ng-click="executePage(page)">{{page}}</li></ul>',
    link:  function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.pages = [];
      scope.$watch('numPages', function(pages) {
        if(!pages) return;
        scope.pages = [];
        for(var i = 1; i <= pages: i++) {
          scope.pages.push(i);
        }
      });
      scope.executePage = function(page) {
        if(scope.pageFn){
          // Additional Logic
          scope.pageFn(page);
        }
      };
    }
  };
})
```

Then in your html you would write the directive like this:

```
<my-directive>
  <div pager="numberOfPages" page-fn="goToPage"></div>
</my-directive>
```

`goToPage` is a function that is defined in the `myDirective` directive and accepts a page parameter. At this point, the paging directive is also abstract enough for you to use in multiple places and not really have to worry about external functionality.

Comment: Yes, but the app has to be as responsive as possible on devices as old as the original iPad, and using ng-repeat results in the page bogging down on said device, even with 20 items with around 8 watchers each. AFAIK, I can't disable two-way data binding on ng-repeat, so I'm left hacking my way through. If there's anything I'm missing though, I'd appreciate the advice.

Comment: ha well I'm afraid the only suggestion I can give is to be open to using other frameworks aside from Angular. It's generally pretty heavy on the JS stack. If you have to circumvent the default functionality of a framework once, you'll have to do it hundreds of times over. This is generally a sign that something else might suit your needs better.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no going back at this stage of development, but I'll take yours and the others' advice to heart, and will play by the rules. Maybe there's a different approach I'm missing. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
    app.directive('foo', function($compile){
   restrict: 'A',
   link: function(scope, elem){
      ... // some logic

      for (var i = 1; i < numberOfPages + 1; i++) {
         elem.append('<li ng-click="bar('+i+')">'+i+'</li>');
    $compile(elem)(scope);
      }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What I've ended up doing is replacing `ng-repeat` in the directive's template with `bindonce`, which minimizes the footprint.

https://github.com/Pasvaz/bindonce