# What happens to ng-click and controller access when added by a directive's link function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have [a simple JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dumbledad/f42upLrd/):

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as mainCtrl">
    <div ng-show="mainCtrl.visible" ng-click="mainCtrl.swap()">Can you see me?</div>
    <div see-me></div>
</div>

angular.module('AngularTestApp', [])
    .controller('MainCtrl', [function () {
        var self = this;
        self.visible = true;
        self.swap = function() {
            self.visible = ! self.visible;
        };
    }])
    .directive('seeMe', [function () {
        return {
            template: 'or me?',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                attrs.$set('ng-show', 'mainCtrl.visible');
                attrs.$set('ng-click', 'mainCtrl.swap()');
        }
    };
}]);
```

Since the default value for a `scope` on a directive's definition object is `false` I would expect the parent's scope to be available and thus for `attrs.$set('ng-click', 'mainCtrl.swap()');` to work, but it does not fire when I click the `div`. Why?

(N.B. I tried adding `$compile` as per [ppa's answer to 'AngularJS - ng-click in directive's link function'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23135620/575530) but that had no effect.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting attributes on an element doesn't process any directives. You'll have to use the `$compile` service to compile the new template with the current `scope` and replace the current element with the compiled element.

```
.directive('seeMe', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
        return {
            template: 'or me?',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                var newElement = $compile('<div ng-show="mainCtrl.visible" ng-click="mainCtrl.swap()">or me?</div>')(scope);
                element.replaceWith(newElement);
        }
    };
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f42upLrd/1/)

Comment: Wow, thanks for that. This looks like a handy way to rewrite code that would have used `replace` before it was deprecated too.

Answer (score 1):

In the question I mention trying `$compile` but I think I messed up injection when I tried that. [c.P.u.1's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28627233/575530) show's how I should have done it. Here's a version of [c.P.u.1's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28627233/575530) which does not replace the current element but compiles it after the additional attributes are added. Note that I need to remove the original directive attribute avoid infinite compile loop (see [Ilan Frumer's answer to 'Angular directive how to add an attribute to the element?'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21688829/575530)).

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl as mainCtrl">
    <div ng-show="mainCtrl.visible" ng-click="mainCtrl.swap()">Can you see me?</div>
    <div see-me></div>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
angular.module('AngularTestApp', [])
.controller('MainCtrl', [function () {
    var self = this;
    self.visible = true;
    self.swap = function() {
        self.visible = ! self.visible;
    };
}])
.directive('seeMe', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        template: 'or me?',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.removeAttr('see-me');
            attrs.$set('ng-show', "mainCtrl.visible");
            attrs.$set('ng-click', "mainCtrl.swap()");
            $compile(element)(scope);
        }
    };
}]);
```

(JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dumbledad/f42upLrd/2/)).